# PL/SQL: Wrong syntax

Tags: sql, plsql, forall

I need to create a PL/SQL anonymous block, which have to copy the data from `t_src` to `t_dest` and the values that are duplicated to be stored in table `t_err`.

`t_src` has two columns filled with data and don't have primary key. 
`t_dest` is empty and column 1 is primary key. When there is exception for duplicate I have to pass it and store the duplicate records in `t_err`. I must use cursors, forall, and `BULK COLLECT`. By now I have created the following block:

```
    DECLARE 
    CURSOR c_copy IS
    select column1, column2
    from t_src;
    TYPE curtype IS TABLE of c_copy%ROWTYPE;
    cursor1 curtype;
 BEGIN 
   OPEN c_copy;
   LOOP 
     FETCH c_copy BULK COLLECT INTO cursor1;
     FORALL c_count IN 1..cursor1.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
     INSERT INTO t_dest          
                VALUES curtype(c_count)              
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    INSERT INTO t_err VALUES curtype(c_count);    
  EXIT WHEN c_copy%NOTFOUND
  END LOOP;
 CLOSE c_copy;
 END
```

Comment: I can't finish the script, it gives me error on the FORALL row

Answer (score 0):

TYPE curtype IS TABLE of c_copy%ROWTYPE;
The above line is causing the issue.

You need to create table type variable  for each of the fields i.e. column1, column2.

TYPE tab_column1 is table of t_src.COLUMN1%TYPE;
TYPE tab_column2 is table of t_src.column2%type;

L_column1 tab_column1;
L_column2 tab_column2;

Then use

FeTCH c_copy BULK COLLECT INTO L_column1,  L_column2;

I have faced similar issue before and this was the workaround that i used for fixing.